# stopPropagation for Material UI Tooltip

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, hover, tooltip, stoppropagation

Need to e.stopPropagation() for child in the Parent container. Both of them are wrapped into Material Ui Tooltip. I get displayed both tooltips if Hover over Child. onOpen={e => e.stopPropagation()} not helping

```
      <Tooltip title="main container">
        <Button style={{ background: "red", color: "white" }}>
          <Tooltip title="child container">
            <Button
              style={{ background: "green", color: "white" }}
            >
              Child
            </Button>
          </Tooltip>
        </Button>
      </Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually [trigger](https://mui.com/components/tooltips/#triggers) opening the tooltips by handling `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` events on both your parent and child buttons and hide parent's tooltip if child's state is opened like this:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Tooltip } from "@mui/material";

export default function App() {
  const [parentOpen, setParentOpen] = useState(false);
  const [childOpen, setChildOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <Tooltip
        title="main container"
        open={!childOpen && parentOpen}
        disableHoverListener
      >
        <Button
          style={{ background: "red", color: "white" }}
          onMouseEnter={() => setParentOpen(true)}
          onMouseLeave={() => setParentOpen(false)}
        >
          <Tooltip
            title="child container"
            open={childOpen}
            disableHoverListener
          >
            <Button
              style={{ background: "green", color: "white" }}
              onMouseEnter={() => setChildOpen(true)}
              onMouseLeave={() => setChildOpen(false)}
            >
              Child
            </Button>
          </Tooltip>
        </Button>
      </Tooltip>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-controlled-tooltip-4e55j?file=/src/App.js:0-1004) for a live working example of this usage.